# Can I automatically resize an image to fit the height of sibling-div (maybe with Bootstrap)?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a section on a webpage that has a few rows of text or other elements. On the right side of this text I would like to show an image that fits the height of the sibling-div (i.e. the total height of text rows). Like this:

[image]

I am using the flex-functionality of Bootstrap with the code below:

```
<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column mb-3 w-100" >
      <div class="p-2 bg-light">Flex item 1</div>
      <div class="p-2 bg-light">Flex item 2</div>
      <div class="p-2 bg-light">Flex item 3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
       <img src="img_avatar3.png" **What can I do here?**/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried some auto-height, max-height, etc... But I can't find a working solution.

Comment: first add **img-responsive** class to image

Comment: It seems like you have no end tag for your flex-row div. Try putting it first.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: you might need to use the col class  ., then for the image itself, you may use custom class made yourself : sizing and object-fit  possible example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/XWbbXXO